# copy a folder under linux server to windows server

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-transfer, copying

I need to find a way to transfer the daily backup folder of my Debian server to a Windows server weekly. What would be the easiest and most stable way to achieve this? Would I definitely need a Samba installation on my Debian server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MS-Windows shared folder:**
You can share data between windows and linux system for such use :
For example you would like to access MS-Windows share called //windowsserver/sharename by mounting to /mnt/win directory under Linux system. So execute these commands:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/win
mount -t smbfs -o username=winntuser,password=mypassword //windowsserver/sharename /mnt/win
```

Next create the password file /etc/sambapasswords:

```
cat > /etc/sambapasswords 
username = winntuser
password = mypassword
```

make sure that only root have access to it

```
chown root:root /etc/sambapasswords
chmod 600 /etc/sambapasswords
```

Add an entry to your /etc/fstab:

```
//windowserver/share /mnt/win smbfs
auto,gid=users,fmask=0664,dmask=0775,iocharset=iso8859-15, credentials=/etc/sambapasswords 0 0
```

Append an entry to your crontab like this, if you need to do a backup daily at 1AM:

```
0 1 * * * cp /path/to/yourbackup /mnt/win
```

**FTP solution:**
you may install a ftp server on your windows machine. filezilla server do perfectly the job.
setup a ftp folder and an account with all required privileges.
Later setup a file named ~/.netrc with this content:

```
machine windowserver
login ftpuser
password ftppassword
```

make sure that only root have access to it:

```
chown root:root ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Append to your backup script this lines that will transfer your backup file remotely to your ftp server:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=yourbackupfile
ftp <<EOF
open windowserver
bin
verbose
prompt
cd ${remote_path}
put ${filename}
bye
EOF
```

Finally add your backup script to your crontab like what we did for first solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with rsync. Set up a rsync server at the Linux machine, and use a [rsync client](http://www.brentnorris.net/rsync.zip) at the Windows machine to get the files.

With rsync, you will be able to resume interrupted transfers

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script in order to communicate with our windowser server.
You need to add a share (ie Samba share) on the windows box :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script d'envoi des archives 

cd /mount directory
mount -t cifs //SMB-SHARE share name/ -o username=USER,password=PASSWORD,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777

umount share
```

Comment: I do almost exactly the same thing as Kronick describes for an hourly copy from a Linux to a Windows machine.

Comment: This is the best, most easy, and most stable way to do this. No servers to set up - just make sure the samba client is installed on the Linux machine, which is probably already is.

Answer (score 1):

Another way will be to actually pull the needed files away from the Linux server from the Windows server, using pscp (from the putty package)

Comment: And like Nik says above, if you use key authentication, you can script it.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup [**freeSSHd**](http://www.freesshd.com/) on the Windows server and script a [**secure copy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346509/automate-scp-file-transfer-using-a-shell-script) from the Debian server.
Also consider setting up [public key authentication](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/) for easier scripting.